# How to handle local push notification in apple watch when paired device is locked?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, apple-watch

I am using local notifications for iPhone with `UNNotificationAction`. 
Push notifications are received on iPhone and apple watch and overall it works fine. But when the paired device (iPhone) is locked, the notification appears on AppleWatch but the action is not triggering the handler function on the iPhone.

I was able to reproduce this error only on watchOS 5+ and when the device is locked. Also, this is very hard to debug, currently I am testing it with printing messages to logs.

```
// handling action from notification
func handleDidReceive(response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("handle action notification")
    // handle logic
    // core data / networking operations

    }


// Registering action categories
class func registerNotificationActions() {

        let action1 = UNNotificationAction(identifier:"identifier1", title:"title 1",options:[])
        let action2 = UNNotificationAction(identifier:"identifier2", title:"title 2",options:[])

        let actionCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "CategoryIdentifier", actions: [action1,action2], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [] )

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([actionCategory])

    }
```

I expect the action to trigger the `handleDidReceive` function, but it is not triggered :/